# HTML/Javascript clean canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I come here for a clean canvas issue in HTML/Javascript. In this canvas, it's use for a signature (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRvU7.png)).

If i use these lines of code :

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;

function save() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.getElementById('source').value = dataURL;
  var fd = new FormData(document.forms["general"]);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('Get', 'convertToPdf.php', true);

  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
      alert('Succesfully uploaded');
    }
  };

  xhr.onload = function() {

  };
  xhr.send(fd);
}

function color(obj) {
  switch (obj.id) {
    case "green":
      x = "green";
      break;
    case "blue":
      x = "blue";
      break;
    case "red":
      x = "red";
      break;
    case "yellow":
      x = "yellow";
      break;
    case "orange":
      x = "orange";
      break;
    case "black":
      x = "black";
      break;
    case "white":
      x = "white";
      break;
  }
  if (x == "white") y = 14;
  else y = 2;

}

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
  ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = x;
  ctx.lineWidth = y;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
  var m = confirm("Want to clear");
  if (m) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
  }
  var conv = new ActiveXObject("pdfServMachine.converter");
  conv.convert("http://www.google.com", "google.pdf", false);
  WScript.Echo("finished conversion");
}


function findxy(res, e) {
  if (res == 'down') {
    prevX = currX;
    prevY = currY;
    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    flag = true;
    dot_flag = true;
    if (dot_flag) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = x;
      ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      dot_flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (res == 'move') {
    if (flag) {
      prevX = currX;
      prevY = currY;
      currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
      draw();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <canvas id="can" width="700" height="200" style="border:2px solid;"></canvas>
</p>
<table align="center">
  <tr align="left">
    <td align="right">
      <input type="submit" name="ss" value="Submit" id="btn" onclick="save();return validateBeforeSubmit(); ">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <input type="button" name="ss" value="clear" id="btn" onclick="erase()">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The clear, works, but if I have a scrollbar in my page, we can't see anything in the canvas!!

So, I was looking for an `function init()` that will be able to write in the canvas wherever you are in the webpage and found this :

```js
function init(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;

  var x = null;
  var y;
  
  canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
  }
  
  canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    x = null;
  } 
  
  canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
    if (x==null) return;
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }  
}
```

But know, the canvas take all 'signature' for where you are in the page, so, if the webpage have a scroll bar, no problem, the canvas still show something if you draw something, but the clear won't work on it.

So, my issue it's that I want to be able to write in the canvas, no matter where it is, and be able, if a click on my button who have the function clear, to clear the canvas.

**EDIT**
Here what my webpage look like:
[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vd8T.png)

Right now, I put it without scrollbar to show, but, at the original size, the page have a scroll. My canvas it's at the bottom of the page, so, when I scroll down, I can't draw in it, but in a page without scroll, I can draw in it and erase it!!

There was the reason that I put the second `init function`, that if there a scrollbar or not, I'm still able to draw in it, that I scroll or not the page, but not for clean it!!

Thanks for you're help

Comment: Apologies, I would love to help but I'm having trouble understanding. The snippets you've provided don't seem to be working as you expected. Could you provide a jsfiddle( https://jsfiddle.net/  ) instead? Secondly, could you be more clear what you mean when you say that you want to be able to write in the canvas, no matter where it is?

Comment: I suppose you mean this https://jsfiddle.net/we242fmt/1/

Right now, if you use the script in a webpage without scrollbar, we can draw in it (like if you go in paint and draw something). But, each time a put this on a webpage that use a scrollbar, nothing happen when you draw on the canvas if this one it's at the end of the webpage, that's why a find the other init function that able to draw on canvas, if this one as at the top or at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/we242fmt/3/

(In the example I purposely moved the canvas down the page using CSS to better demonstrate. You can remove the CSS I've added in to get back to where you were)

What's happening is that you're getting the offset of the canvas element but the offset doesn't take into account how far you've scrolled down the page.

All we need to do is simply adjust the code to incorporate the distance that the user has scrolled:

```
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft + window.scrollX;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY;
```

In your example you don't need to use scrollX because you're not scrolling horizontally, but I included it for the sake of being thorough.

Comment: @Nexis It's no problem!

Comment: Hi zfrisch,

Did you know why in ie, it's make me a bug?
It's work well in firefox and Chrome, but do nothing in internet explorer.

Comment: If I put pageYOffset and pageXOffset insted of window.scrollX and window.scrollY it's work everywhere